# Hadoop KNN using MapReduce not working using Cloudera

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, knn

I am getting this error on executing the following example:
https://github.com/matt-hicks/MapReduce-KNN

> PriviledgedActionException as:hdfs (auth:SIMPLE)
>   cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:
>   /KnnParams.txt#knnParamFile

I tried to debug and i think it is due to below line issue:

> FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("./knnParamFile")

When the file is Cached in main function it is not actually cached properly. I don't know what's the issue. I think the file is not able to retrieve from cached or dont know what.
However the file is there in location.I double checked.

The KNN file contents are :

> 5, 67, 16668, Single, Male, 3

Can any one help me out on this :( I will be thankful of you.

Comment: Did you put that file in hdfs? "./knnParamFile" doesn't look like a valid hdfs path.

Comment: Yes you are right this was the issue thanks